# Angular 5 HttpClient Events

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular5

I was just trying to explore on the new HttpClient. Came to know that there are many HttpClient events are there (Sent, UploadProgress, ResponseHeader, DownloadProgress, Response and User). But I cant find a documentation about whats all these events are doing. Am a newbie to frontend development. May I know whats all these events are doing? Thanks in advance.

tried this:

```
// const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'upload-file-upload', files, {
            //     reportProgress: true
            // });
            // this.http.request(req).subscribe(event => {
            //     // Via this API, you get access to the raw event stream.
            //     // Look for upload progress events.
            //     if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            //         console.log(event, HttpEventType);
            //         this.onUpload.emit(files);
            //       // This is an upload progress event. Compute and show the % done:
            //       const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
            //       console.log(`File is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`);
            //     } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            //       console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
            //     }
            //   });
```

Comment: Check the [official docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)

Comment: I cant find them in official docs cyberpirate.

Comment: I search for the events, but says no record found

Comment: Can you share a code sample that uses those *events* or the webpage where you found those?

Comment: updated my question :)

Comment: In `console.log(event, HttpEventType);` I see HttpEventType prints these events

Comment: Found this from official docs only `https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events`

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEvent it has additional links to individual events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [official docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#request),

> If a `HttpRequest` object is passed directly, an `Observable` of the raw [`HttpEvent`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEvent) stream will be returned.

The events are Http Events which you can find [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEvent)

Comment: Thanks cyberpirate. What about this event `UploadProgress` ? Cant find in documentation

Comment: `UploadProgress` an enum of Type `HttpEventType` in the `HttpProgressEvent` interface. You can find it [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEventType#UploadProgress).